# JSON Data conversion client or server side

Tags: json, user-interface, web, server, data-conversion

I’m working on a project where sever is sending one format of json response .
Consider I have x pages and for each page I need to convert the json to accommodate UI needs.

Approaches:

1. format the JSON on server side as per UI
2. format the JSON on UI side

Please guide me Which approach would be better with some pros and cons .

Answer (score 0):

You should always stick with the server-side rendering as possible for the following reasons,

- A server-side rendered application enables pages to load faster, improving the user experience.
- When rendering server-side, search engines can easily index and crawl content because the content can be rendered before the page is loaded, which is ideal for SEO.
- Webpages are correctly indexed because web browsers prioritize web pages with faster load times.
- Rendering server-side helps efficiently load webpages for users with a slow internet connection or outdated devices.